# Any research showing which is easier for humans? SUB.Domain.com or Domain.com/SUB

Tags: urls

This may be splitting hairs.
But I'm trying to provide a url in an ad.

Two choices are:

Prize.Domain.com
or
Domain.com/prize

I could also, I guess use www.Domain.com/prize

Comment: FWIW, no research to back I just read it somewhere, but don't use *www.* in an ad/print unless the domain is hard to recognize as a url. For example I have a domain stiqr.space that might need the www. but otherwise it unnecessarily complicates it as the www. is a given

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but you could get some useful information from the answers. http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50273/whats-the-difference-between-website-com-directory-and-domain-website-com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally domain.com/campaign is easier on the eyes, it also sets focus on the company or whoever it is that owns the campaign.

From an SEO point of view there are also advantages to doing it that way (from https://moz.com/learn/seo/domain)

> Since search engines keep different metrics for domains than they do
>   subdomains, it is recommended that webmasters place link-worthy
>   content like blogs in subfolders rather than subdomains.

Also, it could be a little easier for the user to navigate to the rest of the site through a url like that since just deleting the /campaign feels more natural than editing the actual domain name.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no research (I'd also be interested if it exists).

For the case you suggest, where you are simply creating a single page as the landing page for your advert, but that is otherwise an extension of your existing site, I agree with @Winter that you should probably put it at https://example.com/prize.

### When to use separate domains

As regards the broader question in your title of subdomains vs paths in general, I don't think it's so easy to answer. There may be no research because the answer varies hugely depending on the situation.

It's more of an architectural choice, which depends very much on the shape of the system, and that this choice then impacts on the rest of your UX design.

The name "domain" (and "subdomain") is a very good description of how humans see and use domains vs paths. When you make something its own domain, it helps it to be considered a different conceptual domain in all senses.

#### Two case studies

I think StackExchange are a good example of how to use subdomains effectively. They had this choice - we could be on stackexchange.com/ux right now. But I think they made exactly the right call in making the UX topic its own subdomain, because they want each of their topic forums to have its own community. And I think that choice has determined how StackExchange is used.

In contrast to StackExchange is [Reddit](https://reddit.com). They also have a website split into communities ([subreddits](https://maximizesocialbusiness.com/subreddits-care-12544/)), but these live at sub-paths of the main domain - e.g.: https://www.reddit.com/r/usability/

Even though subreddits can have their own look and feel, this architectural choice to reject subdomains has meant that the boundaries between subreddits are much less clear than between StackExchange communities. This allows them to do certain things more easily, like have a homepage that pulls together posts from many subreddits, but it also means that subreddits feel like less significant communities in their own right.

I am not making a judgement between whether Reddit's or StackExchange's experience is *better*, but I do think StackExchange's is *cleaner*.

#### Separating experiential domains

So when you make something a domain, it will be much more its own thing. And this means both that it has more freedom to be different from the original, and also that it will be harder to integrate it with the original.

I think this decision should then impact significantly on your design and UX decisions. (Sub)domains should have their own distinct branding (although they may only be subtly different) and should be mostly self-contained with only minimal links off to other domains.

Comment: I think it used to be possible to create a scam using subdomains to lure people away from the real domain, and so for this reason I avoid anything sub-domain like, unless I am completely sure I am willing to trust it, or have nothing to lose (which is never true, so no, basically never).

Comment: how would you create a scam using subdomains? No-one can add subdomains apart from the owner of the DNS to the main domain. So unless you don't own the main domain (e.g. with yourcompany.github.io), you're in complete control.

Comment: Ultimately subdomain spoofing is no easier than domain spoofing. If you have "mycompany.com", someone can easily come along and create "my-company.com" and pretend to be you. Similarly if you have "mycompany.github.io" someone else can create "my-company.github.io". But if they can never create "fake.mycompany.com" or "fake.mycompany.github.io" 'cos you control the higher domains.

Comment: And as far as I'm aware, this has always been the case. I am very interested in computer, and especially internet, security. So @nocomprende if you find a reference to a way in which it used to be possible to spoof subdomains on someone else's domain, please share it, I'm very curious.

Comment: This seemed authoritative: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/watch-out-for-dns-sub-domain-hijacking/ - Once bitten, 2,147,483,648 times shy. If someone tells me something is dangerous, it is permanently written off.

Comment: Ah. This would be a v serious vulnerability - they could point your main domain (example.com) to their own servers and serve a spoofed copy of your website. They only don't do that 'cos they don't want to be detected, they simply create their own secret subdomains to gain the legitimacy of your domain.

Comment: @nocomprende This is not a reason not to create your own subdomains - they are no more at risk than your main domain. But it is a reason to closely monitor your DNS because if someone gains this kind of access your whole domain is horribly vulnerable.

Comment: So, if there are no subdomains, and the bad guys (or women) would not just redirect the main domain, problem solved, eh? If adding '/sub-whatever' on the end is easy and painless, why even bother to do it the other way? Do things in such a way that they *can not* be abused and that is one less thing to worry about at night. That is my approach, anyway. Maybe, if everyone did things this way, we would all be a lot happier. Why create a method that is in any way open to being hijacked? Just don't. A friend was complaining about his car alarm. I said, "my car is 15 years old." No alarm needed.

Comment: @nocomprende I feel like you're willfully misunderstanding at this point (at least your username is appropriate). Every site has DNS. If your DNS is hacked, someone can do *anything* with your site domain. Your use of the main domain or subdomains has *no impact on that risk whatsoever*.

Comment: But, if someone does something to the main (and absolutely only) domain, I would notice right away, right? It is like saying that doors with keyholes are all equally vulnerable. Yes, but if someone breaks down my front door, someone will probably notice. This is the pragmatic approach to security: even if technology is no help whatsoever, I still get to do what makes sense and minimizes the risk. I can still use my brain.

Comment: @nocomprende sure, go with that. Don't worry about how the internet actually works, just pretend it works in a way that makes you feel safe and create your website based on that model. That's fine with me.